# limit definition with bounded function

Tags: limits

I am about to take exam but still there are a lot of logics coming around question .

The function defined in an interval $[-4,4]$ and $\lim _{x\to\:0}\:\:f\left(x\right)=3\:$ Then

A)$\exists\delta>0 \ such\:that \: 0<\left|x\right|<\delta \implies f\left(x\right)\le 3 $

B)$\exists\delta>0 \ such\:that \: 0<\left|x\right|<\delta \implies f\left(x\right) \ge  3 $

C)$\exists\delta>0 \ such\:that \: 0<\left|x\right|<\delta \implies 2<f\left(x\right)<4 $

D)  $-4<f\left(0\right)<4$

E) $\exists\delta>0 \ such\:that \: \left|x\right|<\delta \implies 2<f\left(x\right)<4 $

since we don't know the value of epsilon how I can calculate. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For limit $(\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L)$ the definition should be $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in A, 0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon$$ 
Now compare it to get the correct answer.

---

You can choose any $\epsilon>0$ to get a particular $\delta>0$. You need to understand the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#Limit_of_a_function). D is not correct unless you have further information about continuity at $0$. Remember to exist limit it's not necessary to $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L\ne f(c)$. No, interval can't effect the definition.

---

As you have given, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=3$ then $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x, 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)-3| < \epsilon$$ 
Now if we choose $\epsilon=1$ then
$$0 < |x| < \delta \implies |f(x)-3| <1=2<f(x)<4\tag{C}$$
Don't worry for $\delta$ because we already given that the limit exist.

Comment: what value of eplison I can take

Comment: I think D is correct an

Comment: does interval can effect the defination?

Comment: I update my answer @ifraheem.ajmal

Comment: sir unfortunately I am not getting an answer , I shall be very thankful to you if you can provide the solution

Comment: I add the answer but you really need to grasp the definition @ifraheem.ajmal If my answer clear to you then you can accept it by clicking the check mark.